# lualatex hyphenation issue in fancyhdr, with gregoriotex and multicols, latin text

Tags: luatex, fancyhdr, multicol, hyphenation, gregorio

The problem presents as each word in the header becoming hyphenated with each syllable on its own line, making the header unreasonably tall.  The problem is intermittent, not occurring on every page.

It seems to occur when there is a Gregorian chant score on a page with a multicols environment that in turn triggers or goes over a page break. However, the chant score is NOT a float - it is a paragraph of text in a very strange font. The multicols environments contain only text - no images or scores or floats of any kind. The text between scores changes between multicols or not with great frequency, sometimes spanning pages.  I will put a picture of a typical page (from an original document) before the MWE at the end of this post to show the style I'm trying to copy.

Changing the header to a longish sequence of short, unhyphenable words seems to function fine, so it definitely appears to be a hyphenation issue.

While removing the latin designations in this example "fixes" the problem in some cases, this may be just because spacing changes in the body. It does not fix all cases, so I do not believe it is simply a particular language issue.

Switching from babel to polyglossia for language hyphenation issues does not seem to help, except that polyglossia provides commands \disablehyphenation and \enablehyphenation, which can be used in the header to suppress the problem.  That's a "solution" for me, but maybe not everyone.

The MWE is not so M because I have to include the gregorioscore input for this example.  Gregorio takes a short text description of a chant - a .gabc file - and converts it to a .gtex file with a similar name. You can either use \input to read the .gtex file or the \gregorioscore command to read the .gabc file.  Both are provided in the MWE, just uncomment the one you test with.  They ought to be equivalent. Using the .gtex file would eliminate the need for the gregoriotex package, perhaps, but I'm not sure the fonts to represent the chant would be available on other systems without this.

Picture of typical page (not this page) to show style:
[image: Page from the Nocturnale Romanum, 2002]

MWE.tex

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8

%latin language setting (plus babel package below)
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,latin]{book}

%Use for English
%\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[oldstyle]{libertine}

% Comment out for English
\usepackage[latin]{babel} 

\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry} 

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}

%You may comment this line out if you use the .gtex file input instead of the .gabc file.
%\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex} % for gregorio score inclusion

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\rnum{\thepage}}
%\fancyhead[C]{Feria II in I Nocturno}
%
% English header
% \fancyhead[C]{Feria II in I Nocturn}
%
%optional english long header with small words - works fine in English language setting
%\fancyhead[C]{This Hdr is quite long but has just small words}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{gregoriotex}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\subsection{Feria Secunda}

\subsubsection{In 1 Nocturno}
\vspace*{0.5cm}
%Use only one of the following two lines; the gregorioscore line requires the usepackage{gregoriotex} line above
\input{ExtraTempusPaschale.Secunda.Antiphon.1-5_2_1.gtex}
%\gregorioscore{ExtraTempusPaschale.Secunda.Antiphon.1}
\vspace*{0.5cm}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}{2}
\end{document}
```

File ExtraTempusPaschale.Secunda.Antiphon.1.gabc.  Use with the gregorioscore command if gregoriotex 5.2.1 is installed.  In that case, you don't need the .gtex file below this.

```
name: Dominus ;
office-part: Antiphona;
commentary: {\itshape\mdseries Ps.13,2;\/} Off.m.h.135;
mode: 2;
mode-differential:d;
annotation: 1.Ant;   
annotation: II.d;    
%%
(f3) DO([alt:Extra Tempus Paschale.]h)mi(g)nus(h) <sp>*</sp>( )
 de(f) cœ(g)lo(f) pro(e)spé(g)xit(f) (,)
 su(f)per(e) fí(f)li(h)os(g) hó(e)mi(gh)num.(f) (::) 
<eu> E(h) U(h) O(h) U(g) A(ef) E.(f)  </eu> (::)
```

File ExtraTempusPaschale.Secunda.Antiphon.1-5_2_1.gtex. Do not use if you can compile from the .gabc file above.  Gregorio Tex will create it and include it for you.

```
% File generated by gregorio 5.2.1
\GregorioTeXAPIVersion{5.2.1}%
% Name: Dominus 
\GreBeginHeaders %
\GreHeader{name}{Dominus }%
\GreHeader{office-part}{Antiphona}%
\GreHeader{commentary}{\string\123\string\092itshape\string\092mdseries Ps.13,2;\string\092/\string\125 Off.m.h.135}%
\GreHeader{mode}{2}%
\GreHeader{mode-differential}{d}%
\GreHeader{annotation}{1.Ant}%
\GreHeader{annotation}{II.d}%
\GreEndHeaders %
\GreBeginScore{502c932081554682fd50cc8f4a972b3d670d7f44}{10}{7}{0}{1}{}{4}{\GreInitialClefPosition{3}{0}}%
\GreAnnotationLines{1.Ant}{II.d}%
\GreMode{\GreModeNumber{2}}{}{}%
\GreSetLargestClef{f}{3}{3}{c}{0}{3}%
\GreScoreOpening{%
}{%
\GreSetInitialClef{f}{3}{3}{c}{0}{3}{1}%
}{%
}{\GreSyllable}{\GreSetFirstSyllableText{D}{O}{}{{}{\GreFirstWord{\GreFirstSyllable{\GreFirstSyllableInitial{O}}}}{}}{{\GreFirstWord{\GreFirstSyllable{\GreFirstSyllableInitial{D}}}}{\GreFirstWord{\GreFirstSyllable{O}}}{}}{}}{}{\GreFirstWord}{0}{\GreSetNextSyllable{\GreFirstWord{m}}{\GreFirstWord{i}}{}{\GreFirstWord{m}}{\GreFirstWord{i}}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreSetTextAboveLines{Extra Tempus Paschale.}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{10}{\GreNextCustos{9}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{10}{10}%
}{}{}%
}%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{\GreFirstWord{m}}{\GreFirstWord{i}}{}{\GreFirstWord{m}}{\GreFirstWord{i}}}{}{\GreFirstWord}{0}{\GreSetNextSyllable{\GreFirstWord{n}}{\GreFirstWord{u}}{\GreFirstWord{s}}{\GreFirstWord{n}}{\GreFirstWord{u}\GreFirstWord{s}}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{9}{\GreNextCustos{10}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{9}{9}%
}{}{}%
}%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{\GreFirstWord{n}}{\GreFirstWord{u}}{\GreFirstWord{s}}{\GreFirstWord{n}}{\GreFirstWord{u}\GreFirstWord{s}}}{}{\GreFirstWord}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{}{\GreSpecial{*}}{}{\GreSpecial{*}}{}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{10}{\GreNextCustos{8}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{10}{10}%
}{}{}%
}%
%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{}{\GreSpecial{*}}{}{\GreSpecial{*}}{}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{d}{e}{}{d}{e}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{0}%
\GreEndOfElement{2}{0}{0}%
}%
%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{d}{e}{}{d}{e}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{c}{œ}{}{c}{œ}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{8}{\GreNextCustos{9}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{8}{8}%
}{}{}%
}%
%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{c}{œ}{}{c}{œ}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{0}{\GreSetNextSyllable{l}{o}{}{l}{o}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{9}{\GreNextCustos{8}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{9}{9}%
}{}{}%
}%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{l}{o}{}{l}{o}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{pr}{o}{}{p}{ro}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{8}{\GreNextCustos{7}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{8}{8}%
}{}{}%
}%
%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{pr}{o}{}{p}{ro}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{0}{\GreSetNextSyllable{sp}{é}{}{s}{pé}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{7}{\GreNextCustos{9}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{7}{7}%
}{}{}%
}%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{sp}{é}{}{s}{pé}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{0}{\GreSetNextSyllable{x}{i}{t}{x}{it}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{9}{\GreNextCustos{8}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{9}{9}%
}{}{}%
}%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{x}{i}{t}{x}{it}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{}{}{}{}{}}{}{11}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{8}{\GreNextCustos{8}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{8}{8}%
}{}{}%
}%
%
\GreBarSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{}{}{}{}{}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{s}{u}{}{s}{u}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{0}%
\GreDivisioMinima{0}{}{1}%
}%
%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{s}{u}{}{s}{u}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{0}{\GreSetNextSyllable{p}{e}{r}{p}{er}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{8}{\GreNextCustos{7}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{8}{8}%
}{}{}%
}%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{p}{e}{r}{p}{er}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{f}{í}{}{f}{í}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{7}{\GreNextCustos{8}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{7}{7}%
}{}{}%
}%
%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{f}{í}{}{f}{í}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{0}{\GreSetNextSyllable{l}{i}{}{l}{i}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{8}{\GreNextCustos{10}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{8}{8}%
}{}{}%
}%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{l}{i}{}{l}{i}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{0}{\GreSetNextSyllable{}{o}{s}{o}{s}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{10}{\GreNextCustos{9}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{10}{10}%
}{}{}%
}%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{}{o}{s}{o}{s}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{h}{ó}{}{h}{ó}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{9}{\GreNextCustos{7}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{9}{9}%
}{}{}%
}%
%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{h}{ó}{}{h}{ó}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{0}{\GreSetNextSyllable{m}{i}{}{m}{i}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{7}{\GreNextCustos{9}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{7}{7}%
}{}{}%
}%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{m}{i}{}{m}{i}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{0}{\GreSetNextSyllable{n}{u}{m\GreProtrusion{\GreProtrusionFactor{period}}{.}}{n}{um\GreProtrusion{\GreProtrusionFactor{period}}{.}}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{2}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPesOneNothing}{9}{\GreNextCustos{8}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{10}{9}%
}{}{}%
}%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{n}{u}{m\GreProtrusion{\GreProtrusionFactor{period}}{.}}{n}{um\GreProtrusion{\GreProtrusionFactor{period}}{.}}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{}{}{}{}{}}{}{15}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{8}{\GreNextCustos{10}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{8}{8}%
}{}{}%
}%
%
\GreBarSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{}{}{}{}{}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{ }{E}{}{ }{E}\GreLastSyllableBeforeEUOUAE{1}{0}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{0}%
\GreDivisioFinalis{0}{}%
%
\GreNextSyllableBeginsEUOUAE{1}{0}%
}%
%
\GreBeginEUOUAE{1}%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{ }{E}{}{ }{E}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{}{U}{}{U}{}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{10}{\GreNextCustos{10}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{10}{10}%
}{}{}%
}%
%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{}{U}{}{U}{}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{}{O}{}{O}{}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{10}{\GreNextCustos{10}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{10}{10}%
}{}{}%
}%
%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{}{O}{}{O}{}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{}{U}{}{U}{}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{10}{\GreNextCustos{9}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{10}{10}%
}{}{}%
}%
%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{}{U}{}{U}{}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{}{A}{}{A}{}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{9}{\GreNextCustos{7}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{9}{9}%
}{}{}%
}%
%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{}{A}{}{A}{}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{}{E}{\GreProtrusion{\GreProtrusionFactor{period}}{.}}{E}{\GreProtrusion{\GreProtrusionFactor{period}}{.}}}{}{0}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{2}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPesOneNothing}{7}{\GreNextCustos{8}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{8}{7}%
}{}{}%
}%
%
\GreSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{}{E}{\GreProtrusion{\GreProtrusionFactor{period}}{.}}{E}{\GreProtrusion{\GreProtrusionFactor{period}}{.}}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{}{ }{}{ }{}}{}{15}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{1}%
\GreGlyph{\GreCPPunctum}{8}{\GreNextCustos{9}{}}{0}%
{%
\GreGlyphHeights{8}{8}%
}{}{}%
}%
%
\GreBarSyllable{\GreSetThisSyllable{}{ }{}{ }{}}{}{\GreUnstyled}{1}{\GreSetNextSyllable{}{}{}{}{}\GreLastOfLine}{}{16}{}{%
\GreSyllableNoteCount{0}%
\GreLastOfScore\GreDivisioFinalis{1}{}%
}%
%
\GreEndEUOUAE{1}%
\GreEndScore %
\endinput %
```

Comment: I ran the file as posted, inputting the gtex file and get a one page file but I don't see any tower of one syllable hyphenations?  Can you show an image of the output you get from this page and mark the bad heading?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The problem is only visible if you uncomment the `\fancyhead` command.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger yes I just realised uncomment `\fancyhead[C]{Feria II in I Nocturno}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gregoriotex` sets `\hyphenpenalty` for internal reasons to `-200`. A negative `\hyphenpenalty` means that LuaTeX should consider a line ending with a hyphen as *better* than a line non-hyphenated line. Since in a centered context like your header, there are no other reasons not to make lines longer, LuaTeX will hyphenate whenever possible. You can avoid this by locally changing `\hyphenpenalty` back to a more sensible value for your header.

E.g. change `\fancyhead[C]{Feria II in I Nocturno}` to `\fancyhead[C]{\hyphenpenalty=50 Feria II in I Nocturno}`.

Comment: it can't be the \hyphenpenalty alone, if one remove the multicols environment, it is still -200 but nevertheless the header is okay.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's because of the `\pretolerance`. `multicols` sets it to `-1`, so LuaTeX will always try to hyphenate. Otherwise the issue would only occur if it isn't possible to set the header without hyphenation.

Comment: hm, I wonder who should guard at best against this combination. Should multicol avoid the pretolerance for luatex? Or should fancyhdr reset the values in the header?

Comment: I think that `\hyphnpenalty` is the real issue here. Even if `gregoriotex` needs this internally, they should at least reset it after the score. But otherwise I think that reseting in fancyhdr would make sense (or even in general at the beginning of `\output`. But this triggers the question which values it should be reset too. (Even though it probably doesn't make a big difference since hyphenation shouldn'tbe that common during the output routine)

Comment: yes, I agree about gergoriotex, but imho scores can be broken over pages, so it would probably only solve the problem partly if they reset it at the end.

Comment: I do, indeed, have some scores that go on for three or four pages.  There are not any multicolumn environments involved on most of those pages, obviously.  I am not sure if I've seen the problem on those pages which are wholly taken up with a score or not.

Thanks to everyone - I think this documents the problem sufficiently for any poor soul trying to google it.  I'll leave it to the developers of the various packages to sort out the rest.  I've got more than enough to solve my particular problem.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger As a developer of GregorioTeX, I can tell you that we already save the existing `hyphenpenalty` before changing it at the beginning of the score and then restore the value to the stored value at the end.  We do this with a whole list of settings: `hyphenpenalty`, `exhyphenpenalty`, `doublehyphendemerits`, `finalhyphendemerits`, `brokenpenalty`, `looseness`, `tolerance`, `pretolerance`, `emergencystretch`, `widowpenalty`, `clubpenalty`, `parskip`, `lineskip`, `baselineskip`, and `lineskiplimit`.

Comment: @rpspringuel That's great. Do you know why this restoration doesn't work in this case?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes it would still sometimes have an odd \hyphenpenalty, but as long as no scores are used in the middle of `multicols` it would never have the negative `\hyphenpenalty` and negative `\pretolerance` at the same time, therefore avoiding the issue at hand.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger That baffles me.  When I turn on the macro tracing system in GregorioTeX (package option `debug=trace`) I can see the call for the macro which is supposed to restore the pre-existent values (`\gre@restorepenalties`) at the very end of the score (where it's supposed to be).  The only thing I can think of is that something else is also trying to save and restore `\hyphenpenalty` and it stores the value after GregorioTeX has changed it and then restores it after GregorioTeX has done its restoration.  It's also the only value on our list that isn't restored properly.

Comment: @rpspringuel In the middle of the score, `\GreBeginEUOUAE` gets called, which in turn calls `\GreBeginNLBArea` which sets `\global \gre@hyphenpenaltysave =\gre@space@count@hyphenpenalty` and therefore overwrites the saved value.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Good catch. Obviously we need another save register for the NLBArea so that it doesn’t conflict with the save and restore mechanism of the whole score. I’ll start work on a patch.