# Gregoriotex interferes badly with fancyhdr, how to solve this?

Tags: luatex, fancyhdr, hooks, gregorio, lthooks

This is a sequel to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/581013/113546). But it addresses a different problem.

When the above mentioned question was posed about a year ago, I had not noticed it. By accident I saw it last week, and as it addresses `fancyhdr`, I tried to see what it was about. However, I couldn't reconstruct the problem, maybe because there is now a newer version of `gregoriotex`.

But I found a new problem, which I will show below. `Gregoriotex` destroys multi-line headers/footers, when a score is active at the page break. And it is not possible to solve this by `fancyhdr` alone.

Here is the example. It is a simplified version of one of the examples from the Gregorio documentation (http://gregorio-project.github.io/examples/O_Antiphons/O_Antiphons.zip)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{40pt}
\fancyhead[R]{%
  \parbox{0.4\textwidth}{This is a header with a hyphenated line of text in a parbox}
}

\def\move{\rule[-0.2em]{0.4pt}{1em}\,}

\gresethyphen{force}

\grechangedim{afterinitialshift}{2.2mm}{scalable}
\grechangedim{beforeinitialshift}{2.2mm}{scalable}

\grechangestyle{initial}{%
\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont}%

\grechangestyle{annotation}{\scshape\bfseries\small}

\grechangestaffsize{15}

\begin{document}

\section*{Magnificat}
\vspace{1.5cm}\gresetinitiallines{0}
\gregorioscore{Magnificat}
\gresetinitiallines{1}\vspace{1.5cm}

\end{document}
```

The Magnificat score `Magnificat.gabc` is:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
name: Magnificat;
gabc-copyright: (C) R. Padraic Springuel, This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License.;
office-part: Magnificat;
occasion: A Die 17 Ad Diem 23  Decembris;
transcriber: Br. Samuel Springuel, OSB;
transcription-date: 20131212;
mode: 2;
language: latin;
annotation: ii D;

%%

(f3) () <b><sp>V/</sp></b> Mag(e)ní(fe)fi(eh)cat(h.) á(h)ni(h)ma(h) me(h)<v>\move </v>a(g) Dó(e)mi(ef)num.(f.) (::Z)

<b><sp>V/</sp></b> Et(e) ex(fe)sul(eh)tá(h)vit(h) <v>\move </v>spí(hg)ri(hi)tus(i) me(hi)us(h.) (;)
in(h) De(h)o(h) sa(h)lu(h)tá(h)<v>\move </v>ri(g) me(ef)o.(f.) (::Z)

<b><sp>V/</sp></b> Qui(e)a(fe) re(eh)spé(h)xit(h) hu(h)mil(h)tá(h)tem(h) <v>\move </v>an(hg)cíl(hi)l<v>\ae</v>(i) su(hi)<v>\ae</v>:(h.) (;)
ec(h)ce(h) e(h)nim(h) ex(h) hoc(h) be(h)á(h)tam(h) me(h) di(h)cent(h) om(h)nes(h) ge(h)ne(h)ra(h)<v>\move </v>ti(g)ón(ef)es.(f.) (::Z)

<b><sp>V/</sp></b> Qui(e)a(fe) fe(eh)cit(h) mi(h)hi(h) <v>\move </v>mag(hg)na(hi) qui(i) po(hi)tens(h) est:(h.) (;)
et(h) sanc(h)tum(h) no(h)<v>\move </v>men(g) e(ef)jus.(f.) (::Z)

<b><sp>V/</sp></b> Et(e) mi(fe)se(eh)ri(h)cór(h)di(h)a(h) e(h)jus(h) a(h) pro(h)gé(h)ni(h)<v>\move </v>e(hg) in(hi) pro(i)gé(hi)ni(h)es(h.) (;)
ti(h)mén(h)ti(h)<v>\move </v>bus(g) e(ef)um.(f.) (::Z)

<b><sp>V/</sp></b> Fe(e)cit(fe) po(eh)tén(h)ti(h)am(h) in(h) <v>\move </v>brá(hg)chi(hi)o(i) su(hi)o:(h.) (;)
dis(h)pér(h)sit(h) su(h)pér(h)bos(h) men(h)te(h) cor(h)<v>\move </v>dis(g) su(ef)i.(f.) (::Z)

<b><sp>V/</sp></b> De(e)pó(fe)su(eh)it(h) po(h)<v>\move </v>tén(hg)tes(hi) de(i) se(hi)de,(h.) (;)
et(h) e(h)xal(h)tá(h)<v>\move </v>vit(g) hú(e)mil(ef)es.(f.) (::Z)

<b><sp>V/</sp></b> E(e)su(fe)ri(eh)én(h)tes(h) <v>\move </v>im(hg)plé(hi)vit(i) bo(hi)nis:(h.) (;)
et(h) dí(h)vi(h)tes(h) di(h)mí(h)sit(h) <v>\move </v>in(g)án(ef)es.(f.) (::Z)

<b><sp>V/</sp></b> Sus(e)cé(fe)pit(eh) Is(h)ra(h)el,(h) <v>\move </v>pú(hg)er(hi)um(i) su(hi)um,(h.) (;)
re(h)cor(h)dá(h)tus(h) mi(h)se(h)ri(h)cór(h)di(h)<v>\move\ae</v>(g) su(ef)<v>\ae</v>.(f.) (::Z)

<b><sp>V/</sp></b> Si(e)cut(fe) lo(eh)cú(h)tus(h) est(h) <v>\move </v>ad(hg) pa(hi)tres(i) nos(hi)tros,(h.) (;)
Ab(h)ra(h)ham,(h) et(h) sé(h)mi(h)ni(h) e(h)jus(h) <v>\move </v>in(g) s<v>\'\ae</v>(e)cu(ef)la.(f.) (::Z)

<b><sp>V/</sp></b> Gló(e)ri(fe)a(eh) <v>\move </v>Pa(hg)tri,(hi) et(i) Fí(hi)li(h)o,(h.) (;)
et(h) Spi(h)rí(h)tu(h)<v>\move </v>i(g) Sanc(ef)to.(f.) (::Z)

<b><sp>V/</sp></b> Si(e)cut(fe) er(eh)at(h) in(h) prin(h)ci(h)pí(h)o,(h) <v>\move </v>et(hg) nunc,(hi) et(i) sem(hi)per,(h.) (;)
et(h) in(h) s<v>\'\ae</v>(h)cu(h)la(h) s<v>\ae</v>(h)cu(h)ló(h)<v>\move </v>rum.(g) A(ef)men.(f.) (::e+)
```

When I run this example the header on the first page (which contains the page break inside the score) is truncated. It only has the first line and it isn't hyphenated.

[image]

The second page, where the page break is outside the score has the complete header, and it is hyphenated.

[image]

After a long search I found the cause; it is not a matter of some TeX parameters that have bad values, but by the `latex` code in `gregotiotex`. This means it cannot easily be solved by `fancyhdr.

The problem code is in `gregoriotex.lua`, where it installs two filters. line 751-752 in the current version.

```
  luatexbase.add_to_callback('post_linebreak_filter', post_linebreak, 'gregoriotex.post_linebreak', 1)
  luatexbase.add_to_callback("hyphenate", disable_hyphenation, "gregoriotex.disable_hyphenation", 1)
```

These filters are removed at the end of the score, but if the page break occurs in the score they are active during the output routine, and therefore during the construction of the headers and footers by `fancyhdr`. The first filter does something after the line breaking, I am not sure what exactly, but apparently it removes everything beyond the first line. The second filter inhibits hyphenation.

Because these filters are global, they cannot be easily undone by `fancyhdr`. Even if `fancyhdr` would disable them, they would have to be re-enabled at the end, as they are not restored at the end of a TeX group.

I have been trying several ways to do this and I have come up with some kind of solution which requires cooperation between `gregoriotex` and `fancyhdr`. I'll show one of my solutions in an answer. But I would like to discuss other options. After this discussion I could submit this to `gregoriotex` as an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Any solution to this problem should involve disabling these two filters before `fancyhdr` typesets its headers and footers that are affected, and then resetting them to the values they had at the end. So I define two macros to do that. I don't have any information about whether a score was active, so I just check if the filters are active. I have to keep that information until the end to decide if they should be restored. I could put some booleans in TeX variables, but I decided to build up the command to restore them during the test, by using the luatex `tex.print`. Ideally these macros should be defined inside `gregoriotex`. One problem is that in restoring, the functions needed `post_linebreak` and `disable_hyphenation` are local in `gregoriotex.lua`, so I can't use them outside. I added the following lines to `gregoriotex.lua` to solve this:

```
gregoriotex.post_linebreak               = post_linebreak
gregoriotex.disable_hyphenation          = disable_hyphenation
```

This macro disables the filters and records the code to restore them:

```
\newcommand\gregoriodisable{\edef\filterrestore{\directlua{%
      local b
      b = luatexbase.in_callback('post_linebreak_filter', 'gregoriotex.post_linebreak')
      if b then 
        luatexbase.remove_from_callback('post_linebreak_filter', 'gregoriotex.post_linebreak')
        tex.print("luatexbase.add_to_callback('post_linebreak_filter', gregoriotex.post_linebreak, 'gregoriotex.post_linebreak', 1)")
      end
      b = luatexbase.in_callback('hyphenate', 'gregoriotex.disable_hyphenation')
      if b then 
        luatexbase.remove_from_callback('hyphenate', 'gregoriotex.disable_hyphenation')
        tex.print("luatexbase.add_to_callback('hyphenate', gregoriotex.disable_hyphenation, 'gregoriotex.disable_hyphenation', 1)")
      end
    }}}
```

It builds up a command `\filterrestore` that contains the Lua code to restore the filters that were present.
This is the LaTeX macro to restore these filters:

```
\newcommand\gregorioenable{\directlua{\filterrestore}}
```

And then I can use these in the affected header:

```
\fancyhead[R]{%
  \gregoriodisable
  \parbox{0.4\textwidth}{This is a header with a hyphenated line of text in a parbox}
  \gregorioenable
}
```

Maybe there are simpler ways, but at least this works.

Here is the complete code of the example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{40pt}
\newcommand\filterrestore{}
\newcommand\gregoriodisable{\edef\filterrestore{\directlua{%
      local b
      b = luatexbase.in_callback('post_linebreak_filter', 'gregoriotex.post_linebreak')
      if b then 
        luatexbase.remove_from_callback('post_linebreak_filter', 'gregoriotex.post_linebreak')
        tex.print("luatexbase.add_to_callback('post_linebreak_filter', gregoriotex.post_linebreak, 'gregoriotex.post_linebreak', 1)")
      end
      b = luatexbase.in_callback('hyphenate', 'gregoriotex.disable_hyphenation')
      if b then 
        luatexbase.remove_from_callback('hyphenate', 'gregoriotex.disable_hyphenation')
        tex.print("luatexbase.add_to_callback('hyphenate', gregoriotex.disable_hyphenation, 'gregoriotex.disable_hyphenation', 1)")
      end
    }}}
\newcommand\gregorioenable{\directlua{\filterrestore}}

\fancyhead[R]{%
  \gregoriodisable
  \parbox{0.4\textwidth}{This is a header with a hyphenated line of text in a parbox}
  \gregorioenable
}

\def\move{\rule[-0.2em]{0.4pt}{1em}\,}

\gresethyphen{force}

\grechangedim{afterinitialshift}{2.2mm}{scalable}
\grechangedim{beforeinitialshift}{2.2mm}{scalable}

\grechangestyle{initial}{%
\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont}%

\grechangestyle{annotation}{\scshape\bfseries\small}

\grechangestaffsize{15}

\begin{document}


\section*{Magnificat}
\vspace{1.5cm}\gresetinitiallines{0}
\gregorioscore{Magnificat}
\gresetinitiallines{1}\vspace{1.5cm}

\end{document}
```

It is annoying to have to put these commands in every possibly affected header/footer, so in the next version of `fancyhdr` I am going to put hooks that can be used.

```
\AddToHook{fancyhdr/init}{\gregoriodisable}
\AddToHook{fancyhdr/exit}{\gregorioenable}
```

I this would be done inside `gregoriotex`, then these hooks could be added at the beginning of a score, and removed at the end of it. Then the tests inside `\gregoriodisable` wouldn't be necessary, and the code could be greatly simplified.

As the problem is not limited to `fancyhdr`, but may also affect other packages that construct headers and footers, and maybe also code in `shipout` hooks or packages like `atbegshi`, I think it would be better to execute these macros before and after the output routine. Unfortunately there are no hooks for this, and even if there were, some classes and packages change the output routine and they would also have to provide the same hooks. I don't know what the best solution would be.